# How to parse big XML file using beautiful soup?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse an XML file named `document.xml` which contains around 400000 character (including tags, breakline, space) init find the code below

```
document_xml_file_object = open('document.xml', 'r')
document_xml_file_content = document_xml_file_object.read()

xml_content = BeautifulSoup(document_xml_file_content, 'lxml-xml')
print("XML CONTENT: ", xml_content)
```

when I am printing `xml_content` below is my output:

```
XML CONTENT:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

For the smaller size of files its printing complete XML code. can anyone help me with this why its happening.

Edit : [Click Here](https://pastebin.com/Fk3pBVhM) to see my XML Content.

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: Please share the contents of the XML file.

Comment: sorry its confidential file it contains sensitive information. i cannot share that file but its fully decorated docx file's document.xml file.

Comment: In that case, please post a representative sample of the xml, without dummy information. It's going to be very difficult to answer otherwise.

Comment: @JackFleeting i have added the pastebin link to the questions please find the file.

Comment: @MendelG i have added the pastebin link to the questions please find the file.

Comment: try this: `for i in xml_content: print(i)`

Comment: @grumpyp its not printing anything inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

For large files it better to use line parser like [xml.sax](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.sax.html). `beautifulsoup` will load the whole file in memory and parse, while using `xml.sax` you will use quite less memory.